# Connect to a SQlite file inside a .jar file with JDBC?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, jar

I have an sqlite database to which I access from my Java program with JDBC. The connection is set like this:

```
private final static String dbfilelocation = "\\sql\\";
private final static String dbfilepath = dbfilelocation + "database.sqlite3";

//parse the database
private static void parseAllFromDB() {
    Connection c = connect2db(dbfilepath);
    // Here I get the values from database via connection 'c'
    disconnectfromdb(c);
}

// Connects with sqlite database
private static Connection connect2db(String dbfilename) {
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        String strConnection = "jdbc:sqlite:" + dbfilename;
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(strConnection);
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Manage exceptions
    }
    return c;
}
```

This works as expected.

However, now I want to create a runnable .jar file that contains my 'database.sqlite3' file inside. Then, the database is no longer accesible as until now, since it is inside the .jar. How could I make JDBC to connect to a database that is inside the .jar file? 
Or is it a better practice to have the database always outside the .jar file? In that case, how?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you are able to modify files inside the jar at runtime, and since a SQLite database is just a file, I would assume you can't modify it at runtime either.

Comment: I would only read the data, not modify it. Isn't it possible either?

Comment: Search for `sqlite resource`.